# Click count the link article in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, count, click

I have view

```
 <% @r.each do |g|  %>
   <%= link_to g.title %>
 <% end %>
```

When I click the link i won't to display the count how many people's click this link.

Like this:

```
 <%= link_to g.title %> Click:<%= countclick %>
```

Title Click:45

Comment: It's really, really unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: How clear trying to do this. I need a count how many people view my article.

Comment: Then your question is overly broad, and you should go try to implement a solution and come back for help if you get stuck. You'll need a controller and a model.

Comment: I have a controller on this page and the model, but I don't know how count the click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Article should have countclicks:integer database column.

Than in article show method (I think you use this method to show article):

```
def show
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
count=@article.countclicks+1
@article.update_attributes(:countclicks=> count)
#other code
end
```

And than in index view:

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
<%= link_to "#{article.name}", show_article_path(article)%>
<%=article.countclick %>
<% end %>
```

Or alternatively you can do this via model callbacks.

Comment: how about do not accrue if page with refresh / reload ?

Comment: You can pass with link some params, and method checks, and if params is present, adds countclick, or let user add only one countclick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `link_to` like this, you have to give it a block:

```
<% link_to g.title do %>
  Click <%= countclick %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: But I have undefined local variable or method `countclick. I am new in Rails and how I wrire this method.

Comment: you need to put these numbers in database unless you already done this

Comment: No i don't done this, because I don't know how scaffold or write count in rails.